# Test data generation for neural network handwriting recognition

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, neural-networks

Can someone share some Octave/Matlab code or algorithm to pre-process a photo taken from mobile camera of a handwritten digit.

After pre-processing, the data should have similar characteristics to the [MNIST data set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database) digit images.

I have a neural network trained using the MNIST data set. Now I want to test my implementation by taking handwritten digit images using a phone camera and saving it on my computer.

I want to give this image as input to test my neural net implementation.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Now I doubt such code exists, or if it does it is probably someone's property. In general extraction of something concrete, like in your case finding where the desired digit is, is even a harder problem than classifying it. What I would suggest is to have some spacial information of which part of the photo the digit is, and just cut the image around. If you want exact representation as the MINST data set you gona have to convert it to the corresponding pixel x pixel size.

Comment: It might be easier to create test material by drawing some digits on a touch-screen device and then down-scaling them.

Answer (score 2):

When people train a model using a dataset, they split the data into several parts and do cross-validation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)

If you scientifically want to find out the exact test performance of the model, you see on which portion of the data it is trained on, and test on the remaining.

Comment: On the contrary it is perfectly laudable to test your model on totally new data. We should be encouraging that surely? From his demeanour I'm guessing he already done CV.

Comment: Thanks again for your respose! Yes I have done cross validation already with test data which comes along training data of MNIST. I am looking for a octave code/algo to transform a single handwritten digit image taken from a mobile camera to a 28*28 bit image with characteristics similar to MNIST. Probably some preprocessing of image required to achieve that.

Comment: I still don't get it what is you goal. Would you please clarify?

Comment: I have captured a single digit image through mobile camera. Saved it on computer, need to transform it to 28*28 bit image with characteristic similar to MNIST data so that I can test my NN with that. I need to know what preprocessing required and how that need to be done.

Comment: @user3051413: That's a bit like "I need to do X, so I've done Y, how do I get to X from there?" - what is X in this case, can you explain in more detail why you *have to* start from a mobile photo - it's a lot of work to start from there . . .

Answer (score 1):

There might be something in the Octave forge [image](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/overview.html) package that you could use or adapt to your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is an old topic to answer, but somebody else may need similar code. Here is a MATLAB code that I wrote for my application. It is a bit messy, so I will explain it in general.

```
subject_list = {'X','Y'};

output = cell(1,size(subject_list,2)*30);
for subject = 1:size(subject_list,2)
    uncropped = rgb2gray(imread([subject_list{subject},'.jpg']));
    bw = imcomplement(im2bw(uncropped));
    se = strel('disk',10);
    bw_closed = imclose(bw,se);
    [L,n]= bwlabel(bw_closed);
    stats = regionprops(L);
    mean_array(subject) = mean([stats.Area]);
    mr = 22; mc = 22;
    numbers = cell(1,n);
    for i = 1:n
        if((stats(i).Area > 300) && (stats(i).Area < 3000))
            bs = stats(i).BoundingBox;
            numbers{i}(:,:) = imcomplement(uncropped(round(bs(2)-mr):round(bs(2)+bs(4)+mr),...
                round(bs(1)-mc):round(bs(1)+bs(3)+mc)));
        end
    end
    
    numbers(cellfun(@isempty,numbers))= [];
    
    for i = 1:size(numbers,2)
        output{1,30*(subject-1)+i} = numbers{i} ;
    end
end


MNIST_centmean = [14.9475,15.0064];

for num = 1:size(output,2)
    sample = imresize(im2double(output{num}),[28 28]);
    rp = regionprops(logical(im2bw(sample,0.1)));
    sample_tr = imtranslate(sample,[MNIST_centmean(1) - rp(1).Centroid(1),...
        MNIST_centmean(2)- rp(1).Centroid(2)]);
    sample_tr(sample_tr<=0.05) = 0;
    imwrite(sample_tr,['n_',int2str(num),'.png'],'PNG');
    resized_numbers(num,:) = reshape(sample_tr,[784,1]);
end
```

There are two subjects in `subject_list` each has 30 digits.

- read the `subject.jpg` with `imread` convert it to grayscale apply
  some morphological operation with imclose (this is because some
  digits may not be continous body like 5 or 9 for some subjects)
- label    each digit with `bwlabel` and find their properties with
  `regionprops` (this step is necassary to locate where the digits are)
- take structures which has area between 300 & 3000 that correspond to
  digit size in my case. It depends on resolution of the input image.
- discard empthy cells by usign `cellfun`

  at the second part
- Resize each pacth to 28 x 28 with `imresize` with default bicubic interpolation.
- Translate the center of each pacthes to resemble it into MNIST dataset by using `imtranslate`. Assign the values to 0 which smaller then 0.05 . (bicubic interpolation added an offset to background which is not the case in MNIST)
- Reshaped the patches to 784x1 and stored them into a matrix (this is
  default size for NN trained with MNIST)